# Feel electric shocks after using MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I know many people would feel electric shocks when touching a charging MacBook. However, my situation is the opposite: after using MacBook, for example, if I touch the mental door handle, I will be shocked.

I've used this MacBook for more than a year but this just happened recently.

Comment: Your room is dry. You can't store electricity in your body from your Mac and discharge it away from the Mac.

Comment: Don't wear anything made of man-made material. Wear cotton, linen or wool; shoes of cotton or leather with leather or real rubber soles…  they don't build up static in the same way. Avoid nylon carpets too.

Comment: I think the problem is that my room was way too dry. After I turn on windows occasionally, it's become much better.